# PHP read Array to String

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My Array: http://pastebin.com/P6p10nFR (too long)

How can I get only the hostname?

```
foreach($gmod_results as $value)
{
 echo $value['server']['hostname'];
}
```

doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly call it

```
$gmod_results['server']['hostname'];
```

Comment: $gmod_results["server"]["hostname"] :)
Thanks!